# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'. Expected a property name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I'm using Slim. When I describe a `javascript:` block, I use this inside the JS code:

```
javascript:
    var tteesstt = #{users.select(:id, :email).order(:email).to_json};
```

But I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'. Expected a property name.

I tried to wrap in `JSON.parse()`, but it did not help.

Tell me, please, how to solve the problem?

Comment: You have a space after the colon before `email` in `.order(: email).to_json}`

Comment: @mindlis This is just a typo on stackoverflow. In the project code everything is fine in this place.

Comment: Can you show slim template more.. ? Probably the whole `javascript:` block

Comment: @ArupRakshit Updated the code in the question.

Comment: should not it be `- users = User.all.limit(5)` ? Also try `var tteesstt = JSON.parse("#{users.select(:id, :email).order(:email).to_json}");`

Comment: @ArupRakshit Why do you find fault with such trifles that don't in any way influence the error? This code is commented out. It was added here for your understanding. Okay. I deleted it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit As I wrote above - `JSON.parse()` doesn't help.

Comment: Did you wrote exactly how I wrote it?

Comment: Try `var tteesstt = #{raw users.select(:id, :email).order(:email).to_json};`

Comment: @ArupRakshit Copied and pasted. Yes.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh `raw` helped. But this is exactly correct?

Comment: @Colibri wait..

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Where did you see that `raw` use? Link?

Comment: @Colibri what do you mean _exactly correct_?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh `raw` is `stringish.to_s.html_safe` => `html_safe`. It seems to me that this is a little dangerous... Or is everything okay?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I don't have a link. I have faced this _exact_ issue a lot of times and `raw` helps (at least in my cases).

Comment: @Colibri Using `raw`in this case is totally okay. Please check in browser console, if you have the value of `tteesstt` correct. Can you access the data easily?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yes, `raw` helped. In the browser console everything is visible. Thank you.

Comment: @Colibri This was answered already.. Just had to search a lot..

Comment: @Colibri Avoid `raw`, do it in Slim way..

Comment: @ArupRakshit Though I like your syntax, any reason to do that i.e. avoid `raw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Slim](https://github.com/fs/rails-base/issues/363), we can do assign JSON data as JS object using `{{}}`.

```
javascript:
  var tteesstt = #{{users.select(:id, :email).order(:email).to_json}};
  console.log(tteesstt); // ensures it gets the data as expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON string must have some special characters which are causing the error. You can use [`raw`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw) to fix it:

```
javascript:
  var tteesstt = #{raw users.select(:id, :email).order(:email).to_json};
```

From the definition:

> This method outputs without escaping a string. Since escaping tags is now default, this can be used when you don’t want Rails to automatically escape tags.